# Did tensorflow at any point change 'tensorflow.sub' into 'tensorflow.subtract'?

Tags: tensorflow

I was testing some code I was given and got an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sub'
```

The module referred to is TensorFlow. To investigate this error I started looking into the TensorFlow source code and found a function 'tensorflow.subtract'. Replacing 'sub' by 'subtract' made the error go away.

However now I am still wondering why the error occurred in the first place. I can think of 2 reasons:

1. At some point TensorFlow renamed 'sub' to 'subtract' and the code I was given hasn't yet updated to accommodate that change. Changing 'sub' to 'subtract' simply updated the code to the newer version of TensorFlow
2. I have made some mistake in importing the wrong libraries and TensorFlow does actually have a 'sub' function. This would mean that changing to 'subtract' potentially altered the workings of the program.

Can anyone give advice on what the most likely scenario is here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TensorFlow 1.0 release contained multiple breaking changes to the API, including the renaming of `tf.sub` to `tf.subtract` (likewise, `tf.mul` was renamed to `tf.multiply` et cetera). Comprehensive lists of all changes can be found here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.0.0